# Problema relacionado con focos

Tags: javascript, html, css, eventos

Tengo un modal con la propiedad **tabIndex** especificada (para que sea capaz de recibir foco) y dentro de ese modal tengo un input (que por defecto recibe foco). Al dar click afuera del modal, se dispara un evento onblur asociado que lo elimina (hasta aquí todo bien), pero también se dispara al enfocar el input que está dentro del modal (lógico que pase). Mi objetivo es evitar ese comportamiento.

Pudiera simplemente colocar el modal dentro de un div padre con **position:absolute** e **inset:0px**, pero mi objetivo es que lo que está detrás del modal sea interactuable. Y si le pongo **pointer-events:none** a ese div padre sería como si no existiera. Para eso tengo otra función que me genera un modal con un div padre con **backdrop-filter:blur(10px)** para que resalte el modal.

Aquí tengo algo de código:

```
const Modal = CrearModalSinDivPadre ('Título') //Función predefinida.
Modal.tabIndex = 0
Modal.addEventListener ('blur', () => Modal.remove ()) //Funcion flecha para escribir menos, aunque no sirve this, pero no importa :-)
const Input = Modal.CrearElemento ({ tagName: 'input' }) //Otra función predefinida que me genera un input.
```

Comment: Hola, perdona si soy yo. Pero a mi percepsión, no es claro lo que te sucede. Según lo que expones entiendo que se ejecuta el focus por defecto y cuando das click fuera ejecuta el onblur, hasta allí es claro. El comportamiento normal, pero que vuelve a dispararse al enfocar nuevamente el input? el onfocus? o se te dispara el onblur? creería que hablas del onfocus, deseas que no se dispare el onfocus cuando hagas foco en un input?

Comment: Hola, podrías darnos una demo funcional y dar más código para ayudar de mejor manera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la función de respuesta al evento, compara e.target con el input del modal. Y si coincide, ignóralo

Por ejemplo, esta función creo que hace algo parecido a lo que comentas. Al hacer click sobre el documento, comparo el popup (container), que en mi caso es un div cuya ID empieza por "editar", con e.target. Si coinciden o e.target es un antecesor, lo ignoro. Si no, se trata de cualquier otro objeto de la página y por tanto cierro el popup (container)

```
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
                var container = $("div[id ^= 'editar']");

                // if the target of the click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container
                if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
                    container.slideUp('fast');
                }
});
```